# Maillog help - ' removed '

Tags: email-server

I'm seeing some strange behavior from the maillog while tailing it and I'm wondering how to know if it a hack, whereby bad emailers (spammers) use legitimate mail servers behind the scenes to send their spam. This will obviously end up getting the poor innocent guy blocked.

But my question for what looks like a legitimate send also - immediately after I get the line removed. Does this mean it was going to be sent but then got removed.

e.g.:

```
Feb 11 16:04:25 beo postfix/smtp[23598]: 7A3A4121BD1: to=<cTt@books-bestsellers.info>, relay=smtp.secureserver.net[216.69.186.201]:25, delay=3, delays=0.13/0/1.8/1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok:  Message 2129575172 accepted)

Feb 11 16:04:25 beo postfix/qmgr[1736]: 7A3A4121BD1: removed
```

does the removed line mean anything here ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means the message was removed from the mail server's local queue because it was successfully sent on to the destination mail server.